# Conditional formatting based on value in corresponding row of named range

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

See screenshot below.

Column B is a named range `curUnit`. There is another named range `unitCount` with the value of 3. I am trying to conditionally format rows 8 through 12 using the formula `=curUnit>unitCount`, so that is the unit count is 3, rows 10-12 will be formatted. If I set up the formula in cell E8 using the formula `=$B8>unitCount` and copy it down, it works correctly. However, when I use the named range `curUnit`, nothing happens?

I know the formula works, because if I enter the formula `=curUnit>UnitCount` in J10, it returns TRUE.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this version

`=INDEX(curUnit,ROW()-MIN(ROW(curUnit))+1)>unitCount`

Comment: That would work, but my goal is to simplify the formulas. Currently, I'm using $B7 and it works, but it's not as clean as I would like it.

Comment: Personally I would use just the cell references. If you use a named range you need a formula like I suggested to extract the specific cell from the named range

Comment: I'll trust your expertise and use the cell reference. Thanks.